# Move a child element to the bottom of the parent node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**So I have a question about XSL:**
I have a bunch of elements that contain a child element that gets renamed and moved with a certain update. I am trying to handle that transformation. The example below will give a better idea.

**Before:**

```
<DGS>
  <DG>
   <FallbackGroup>
      <name>name</name>
      <timeout>20</timeout>
   </FallbackGroup>
   <CallRouting>
       <route>route</route>
   </CallRouting>
  </DG>
</DGS>
```

**After:**

```
<DGS>
  <DG>
   <CallRouting>
       <route>route</route>
   </CallRouting>
   <FallbackGroup>
      <name>name</name>
      <timeout>20</timeout>
   </FallbackGroup>
  </DG>
</DGS>
```

And I have to do this for a number of these individual `<DG>` elements. I have looked at a lot of similar questions on here about this but none of their solutions were doing what I wanted them to do. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To change the order of the child elements of the `<DG>` element you can use the *identity template*  in combination with the following:

```
<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>  

<!-- reorders the DG element --> 
<xsl:template match="DG">
  <xsl:copy>                                 <!-- copies DG element -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="CallRouting" />     <!-- copies CallRouting element -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="FallbackGroup" />   <!-- copies FallbackGroup element -->
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

**The output is:**

```
<DGS>
    <DG>
        <CallRouting>
            <route>route</route>
        </CallRouting>
        <FallbackGroup>
            <name>name</name>
            <timeout>20</timeout>
        </FallbackGroup>
    </DG>
</DGS>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source `DG` element has more than 2 child elements and you want
to move `FallbackGroup` to the end, then try a bit more general solution.

- The template matching `DG` should start from copying all children
  **except** `FallbackGroup`.
- Then it should copy (the only remaining) `FallbackGroup`.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="DG">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="* except FallbackGroup"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="FallbackGroup"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /></xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Given that you use `except` which is not available in XSLT 1 you could as well use another XPath/XSLT 2 feature and combine the two `copy-of`s into one: `<xsl:copy-of select="* except FallbackGroup, FallbackGroup"/>`.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo what would I use in place of except given that I am needing to use XSLT 1?

Comment: You may use `<xsl:copy-of select="*[name() != 'FallbackGroup']"/>` (I forgot that *except* is available as of version 2.0).